How do closed cycle liquid engines actually work?
I've been researching Liquid Engines for quite a while now. I understand that there are two types of liquid engines, Closed cycle and Open cycle (Gas generator cycle). Open cycle engines simply let the exhaust from the turbine out through a different opening (according to my understanding). What I don't understand is, do Closed cycle engines somehow use that "exhaust" and guide to the combustion chamber for combustion. If so, how does it happen? Or if I'm wrong, what's really the difference?

The image above made by me, shows how I think an open cycle engine works.

This is quite a good understanding. Only nitpicks: the regen jacket flow is wonky & the two propellants do NOT mix above the injector (this is why the injector exists, to mix them BELOW the injector)! Also, a preburner isn't a mysterious box, it's basically just a smaller rocket engine, manifolds, injector, chamber, & all, without a full nozzle :)

ohhh thank you so much!, that was quite helpful (:

Yes, closed-cycle engines take the (now gaseous) preburner exhaust & indeed guide it through the injector manifold, injector face, & into the combustion chamber to be fully combusted.
For a fuel-rich preburner, the preburner exhaust contains a small fraction of combustion products but still predominantly unburnt fuel. The same goes for an oxidizer-rich preburner (predominantly uncombusted oxidizer).
Injecting vapor instead of liquid has many advantages, not least of which is you do not have to wait for droplet formation, primary atomization (this occurs when fluid instabilities caused by the difference in momenta on the surface of the droplet between the liquid & surrounding gas phases produce growing curvature in the interface which eventually rips the droplet apart into smaller ones), & finally secondary atomization (dominated by evaporation) to finally have vapor which is ready to mix & then finally begin combustion.
You can just mix the vapors & combust.

Everything in a fluid system flows from high to low pressure. The pump must ALWAYS generate a higher pressure than the outlet, (which is itself higher than anything else downstream of it). The high pressure in the pump exerts a stalling torque on the drive shaft. Therefore, the driving torque from the turbine must be greater than or equal to the stalling torque to allow to pump to continue operation.
